# Trying to make an XML reader work in C ++

Tags: c++, xml, msxml

I am trying to read some XML code from a website, and am having a bit of trouble figuring out where my errors are.  Using the code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415788/read-write-xml-file-in-c) extremely useful post, I am trying to read a file that I have saved to my desktop ("H:\MyName\Desktop\secLendingXML.cfm.xml").  The code is below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#import <msxml6.dll> rename_namespace(_T("MSXML"))

int main(/*int argc, char* argv[]*/)
{
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL); 
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    try
    {
        MSXML::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr xmlDoc;
        hr = xmlDoc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML::DOMDocument60), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
        // TODO: if (FAILED(hr))...
        if (xmlDoc->load(_T("H:\MyName\Desktop\secLendingXML.cfm.xml")) != VARIANT_TRUE)
        {
            printf("Unable to load input.xml\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("XML was successfully loaded\n");

            xmlDoc->setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
            MSXML::IXMLDOMNodeListPtr wheels = xmlDoc->selectNodes("/Car/Wheels/*");
            printf("Car has %u wheels\n", wheels->Getlength());

            MSXML::IXMLDOMNodePtr node;
            node = xmlDoc->createNode(MSXML::NODE_ELEMENT, _T("Engine"), _T(""));
            node->text = _T("Engine 1.0");
            xmlDoc->documentElement->appendChild(node);
            hr = xmlDoc->save(_T("output.xml"));
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                printf("output.xml successfully saved\n");
        }
    }
    catch (_com_error &e)
    {
        printf("ERROR: %ws\n", e.ErrorMessage());
    }
    CoUninitialize();
}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
```

}

The message "Unable to load input.xml" always shows, so I know I'm not having an error, but that the code is unable to load my XML file.

Do I need to save the XML file in a different location?  Is the ".cfm" before the ".xml" screwing with the reading process?

To give an idea of my intended direction, I want to be able to load the XML file from the [New York Fed website](http://www.newyorkfed.org/markets/seclend/sec_lendop.cfm) and read it into some sort of data file where I can automate the data retrieving process.  That way, whenever the website is updated, I will automatically be notified, and it will be reflected by the change in the data file that I will have saved somewhere on my computer.  If anyone also wants to help with how I go about that part - poll intervals, tracking website changes, etc. - that would also be appreciated.

Thank you for any and all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to escape the backslashes in your path string? e.g.

```
xmlDoc->load(_T("H:\\MyName\\Desktop\\secLendingXML.cfm.xml")
```

Comment: Nailed it!  Thanks, I totally spaced on that one.  I'll leave it open in case anyone has some advice for the second part of my question, but I'll accept your answer once I'm allowed.

Comment: do you think you could take a look at the XML file from the NY Fed.  I can't seem to get it into a neat dataset.