# Using XML file data in arithmetic calculations by using MSXML

Tags: c++, xml, msxml

I am trying to read node values and do some arithmetic calculations. This `<xmin>174</xmin>` is the line and I want to read `174` and do some arithmetic calculations e.g. using as an integer.
The code below is created for string format. I tired `get_nodeValue, get_attributes` instead of `get_text` but I could not display the number. I got some unrelevant numbers, I guess they indicate the address.

```
IXMLDOMNode *pNode = NULL;
BSTR name = NULL;
BSTR NpdeName = NULL;
CHK_HR(pNode->get_nodeName(&bstrNodeName));
printf("Node (%d), <%S>:\n", i, bstrNodeName);
CHK_HR(pNode->get_text(&name));
printf("\t%S\n", name);
```

The codes below I already tried.

```
IXMLDOMNamedNodeMap *attribute;
CHK_HR(pNode->get_attributes(&attribute));
printf("\t%d\n", attribute);
```

AND

```
VARIANT value;
CHK_HR(pNode->get_nodeValue(&value));
printf("\t%d\n", value);
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This can maybe help? I usually used those XPath expressions while selecting the value of concrete node: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415788/read-write-xml-file-in-c/9007771#9007771

Comment: I converted `BSTR name` into `int` by using `int value = _wtoi(name)`. This works fine.