# How to parse a XML document in c++

Tags: c++, xml

I have a xml file and I need to build a program that read the xml in c++, is there any good xml parser api in c++ to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boost and XML (c++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042855/boost-and-xml-c)

Comment: as mentioned in the comment above. could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042855/boost-and-xml-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read Write XML File In C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415788/read-write-xml-file-in-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xerces-C++ is a validating XML parser written in a portable subset of C++. Xerces-C++ makes it easy to give your application the ability to read and write XML data

http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/

Answer (score 0):

You can see a lot of advices here [What is the best open XML parser for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/170686/best-open-xml-parser-for-c)
By the way, if you are developing with qt, you can use it's API for XML like QXmlSimpleReader.